# Use of function inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I am trying to call functions inside a for loop, but I am not successful.
Is it possible to call functions in Python 3.x like you call subroutines in Excel?

Here is the code I tried but I do not get any output.

```
def my_fun1(i):
    x=+i
    return x
def my_func2(x1)
    print(x1)

test_rng=range(124,124+100)

for i in test_rng:

    my_fun1(i)
    print(x)
    my_fun2(x)
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you have and output you want ? Right now If I have to take a guess I would say you have a probleme with the variable lifetime and mutability.

Comment: Yes, you can call functions in a loop. What problem are you having?

Comment: x inside my_fun1 as well as inside for loop is not defined

Comment: @MichaelBianconi It's *defining* `x`; note that it's `x = +i`, not `x += i`.

Comment: Using `x` *after* calling `my_fun1` is an issue, though.

Comment: The issue you are probably experiencing is due to scopes... I would suggest searching python scopes...

Comment: Per some of your suggestions I corrected my code.

Comment: I corrected my code based on comments I received.

Comment: I made corrections per comments but i still do not get any output. here is the updated code import pandas as pd
x=0
def my_fun1(i):
    x =x+i
    return x
def my_func2(x1):
    print(x1)

test_rng=range(124,124+100)

for i in test_rng:
    my_fun1(i)
    print(x)
    my_fun2(x)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible but your code would not work because `x` inside the loop will be unknown:

```
for i in test_rng:
    my_fun1(i)
    print(x)
    my_fun2(x)
```

---

Possibly, you want to do something like:

```
for i in test_rng:
    x = my_fun1(i)
    print(x)
    my_fun2(x)
```

---

You may also want to double-check the code in `my_fun1()`:

```
def my_fun1(i):
    x=+i
    return x
```

as the use of `x=+i` may suggest you are trying to do something different from `x = i`, which is essentially what your code is doing: `x=+i` -> `x = (+i)` -> `x = i`

Comment: With corrections suggested I still do not get any output when I execute the cell. x=my_fun1(i) gives me error: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment. Any ideas to change code so that I can get output when I execute the cell?

Comment: @GhanshyamBhat You can check yourself that with the proposed modification it runs without errors: https://repl.it/@RiccardoMetere1/GentleVariableApplicationpackage

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a wrong logic and I am also assuming that the variable `x` is globally defined. See below.

```
def my_fun1(i):
    x=+i#I am assuming you want this x+=i
    return x
def my_func2(x1)
    print(x1)

test_rng=range(124,124+100)

for i in test_rng:

    my_fun1(i)
    print(x)
    my_fun2(x)
```

Comment: The syntax isn't incorrect, just python would interpret `x=+i` as assigning the unary plus operation on `i` to `x`... :)

Comment: Oh yes, didnt think of that. Updated my answer.